# Checking the correctness of the unpacked binary data that contains several datatypes inside it

Tags: php, unpack

I have 20 lines of binary data, The size of each line is 47 bytes, each line hold much information with different lengths and formats as the following:

```
Packets description (I will put one packet of each kind to simplify the question)

    <CRC>: 2 Bytes
    
    offset  0 / 2 bytes: CR = 16-bit CRC - Checksum of all following Bytes.
    
    <msgID>: 2 Bytes
    
    offset  0 / 1 byte:  MN = Incrementing message number
    offset  1 / 1 byte:  SI = unique ID of the datagram structure (0x80 = LoRain payload structure)
    
    <info>: 10 Bytes
    
    offset  0 / 1 byte:  SV = payload structure subversion (0x01 -> version 1.00)
    offset  1 / 2 bytes: HW = HW version (LSB = version 0.01)
    offset  3 / 2 bytes: FW = FW version (LSB = version 0.01)
    offset  5 / 1 byte:  DS = device status
    offset  6 / 4 bytes: SN = 32-bit device serial number (the same format like at iMetos)
    
    <battery>: 2 Bytes
    
    offset  0 / 2 bytes: 16-bit unsigned value of battery voltage (LSB = 1 mV)
                 Sensor code: 0x0007
    ......
    ......
    <vpd>: 4 Bytes
    
    offset  0 / 2 bytes: 16-bit unsigned average value of Vapour Pressure Deficit (LSB = 0.01 kPa)
    ....

   <dewPoint>: 4 Bytes

   offset  0 / 2 bytes: 16-bit signed average value of deltaT (LSB = 0.01 degree C.)
   ....
    
    <leaf_wetness>: 1 Byte
    
    offset  0 / 1 byte:  8-bit unsigned value of leaf wetness time (LSB = 1 minute)
                 Sensor code: 0x0004
```

Note#1: all multi-byte binary fields are ordered `little-endian`.

Note#2: offset in general means the number of bytes after a certain point, so `offset 6 / 4`  is 4 bytes after the byte #6.

In order to unpack the data correctly, I was thinking that I need to use different formats for each offset Just like the code below, I'm cutting the binary string that consists of 47 bytes to many pieces according to the offset that has been described above, I just want to make sure that I have used the correct unpacking formats for each offset.

```
  private function initSensorObject($binary_data){
        $sensor = new Sensor();
        $sensor->sv = unpack('C', substr($binary_data, 4, 1))[1];
        $sensor->hw_version = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 5, 2))[1]; // gives numbers like 101, and I think I it's not correct, it should give something like 1.10
        $sensor->fw_version = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 7, 2))[1];
        $sensor->device_status = unpack('C', substr($binary_data, 9, 1))[1];
        $sensor->serial_number = unpack('V', substr($binary_data, 10, 4))[1];
        $sensor->battery = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 14, 2))[1];
        $sensor->solar = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 16, 2))[1];
        $sensor->precipitation = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 18, 2))[1];
        $sensor->avg_air_temp = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 20, 2))[1]; // gives numbers like 359, and it should give me doubles like 15.62
        $sensor->min_air_temp = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 22, 2))[1];
        $sensor->max_air_temp = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 24, 2))[1];
        $sensor->avg_humidity = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 26, 2))[1];
        $sensor->min_humidity = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 28, 2))[1];
        $sensor->max_humidity = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 30, 2))[1];
        $sensor->avg_deltaT = unpack('s', substr($binary_data, 32, 2))[1];
        $sensor->min_deltaT = unpack('s', substr($binary_data, 34, 2))[1];
        $sensor->max_deltaT = unpack('s', substr($binary_data, 36, 2))[1];
        $sensor->avg_dewpoint = unpack('s', substr($binary_data, 38, 2))[1];
        $sensor->min_dewpoint = unpack('s', substr($binary_data, 40, 2))[1];
        $sensor->avg_vpd = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 42, 2))[1];
        $sensor->min_vpd = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 44, 2))[1];
        $sensor->leaf_wetness = unpack('C', substr($binary_data, 46, 1))[1];
        return $sensor;
    }
```

I

Comment: You need to pay attention when it says things like *LSB = version 0.01* as this means when it's 2 bytes the least significant byte(LSB) should be `* 0.01`.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for the heads up, Can you please post me a similar so questions for that?